# cURL -F in iOS?

Tags: ios, api, post, curl, instagram

I Am Trying to access this URL using RestKit

```
curl -F 'access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN' https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
```

now I have done some reading and found that the -F refers to form data that's attached to the POST request.

but I am unsure of how to convert this curl instruction to the iOS equivalent.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of that framework you are trying to use?

Comment: Hi yes i have managed to get the GET requests working perfectly and it maps superbly.

The POST is proving challenging though. i have done a lot of searching but none of the example (or documentation) include for -F

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a library called ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/. It makes many things, including constructing POSTs very simple

**EDIT**

Sorry, didn't see you are using RestKit already - my brain read it simply as REST.  Ignore my answer!

Comment: Hi there do you recommend that i switch from RestKit to ASIHTTPRequest? because there is no reason specifically i chose RK, well simply because of the nice object mapping. I have heard that MKNetworking is apparently a newer lib that incorporates qualities of ASIHTTP and AFNetworking. any experience working with those?

Comment: Hi, to be honest, when I first got into the whole business of calling services from iOS I actually looked into RestKit, and it did look good. In the end I went with ASIHTTPRequest because I didn't have a REST server - the server I am using only has "JSON RPC" if you will - eg everything is done using POST, I think in REST terms this is maybe called an action.... Also at the time I didn't even understand what REST was all about.  It's really up to you I guess what you want to do - but I would say if you have actual REST services, then you'll probably have an easier time of things using RestKit